# Loading Very Large data(over 1milion records) in RadGridview and having filtering/sorting/grouping functionality

Tags: c#, performance, filtering, telerik-grid, large-data

I am using telerik components (radgridview) in my project and i want to load huge data typically more than 1,000,000 records from SQL server database.
I have tried two scenarios:

1- I have used virtual mode and works fine but i will lose filtering/sorting/grouping functionality(which i need them somehow).

2- At first i load about 1000 records, and then i run a BackGroundWorker which adds rows  to my grid in a for loop, in this way i cant interact with my grid properly(because it is invoking more than 100 times in a sec).

does anyone know how to enable filtering/sorting/grouping in virtual mode?
or any other solutions to keep both filtering/sorting/grouping and performance together?

I Forgot to mention that the project is WindowsFormApplication!
Thank you very much

Comment: I doubt you'll get the browser to handle such a data load. Youll properly need to work with paging.

Comment: I Forgot to mention that the project is **WindowsFormApplication**!

Comment: I don't think the approach changes much - I think you'll still need to work on paged set instead of all the data at once - if you want to handle it via an UI

Comment: You are right, i should use paging, but how about the filtering and ... issue?!

Comment: You search out the proper data based on your criterias and deliver the correct page/pagesize.